# function to return index of an object in a deeply nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexing

I need to perhaps write a function that just outputs the index of an object inside an array, obviously, using $.inArray returns this just fine in the example below.

```
array = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$.inArray('one', array) // 0
```

With a more elaborate array, How can I find the index of the objects nested within?

```
array = [
    {
        name: 'One', // index??
        data: {
            title: 'Title One',
            content: 'Content One'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Two',
        data: {
            title: 'Title Two',
            content: 'Content Two'
        }
    },
    {
        name: 'Three',
        data: {
            title: 'Title Three',
            content: 'Content Three'
        }
    }
];
```

I've heard of the $.grep() method, indexOf() .. not sure which one to use to just return an integer of the index the object is in

Comment: None of those functions handle multi-dimensional arrays. You'll have to roll your own search function. indexof/grep can be used at each level of the array, but moving between levels is up to you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need a pre-written function, just iterate over your array and compare the `name` property:

```
function findValue(array, nameWeAreLookingFor) {
    for(var i = 0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if(array[i].name === nameWeAreLookingFor) return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No built in functions.. but it's easy to write all flavours of your own. And as an exercise you can also use them to extend jQuery,

```
var array = [{
    name: 'One',
    // index??
    data: {
        title: 'Title One',
        content: 'Content One'
    }},
{
    name: 'Two',
    data: {
        title: 'Title Two',
        content: 'Content Two'
    }},
{
    name: 'Three',
    data: {
        title: 'Title Three',
        content: 'Content Three'
    }}];

function findByName(name) {
    var index;
    $(array).each(function(i, e) {
        if (e.name && e.name == name) {
            index = i;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return index;
}
console.log(findByName("One")); // prints 0

// and now even better ... find by any property


function findByProperty(objects, prop, value) {
    var index;
    $(objects).each(function(i, e) {
        if (e[prop] && e[prop] == value) {
            index = i;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return index;
}

// usage
var index = findByProperty(array, "name", "One");
console.log(index); // prints 0
index = findByProperty(array, "name", "Three");
console.log(index); // prints 2
// and even more powerful


function findByFilter(objects, filter) {
    var index;
    $(objects).each(function(i, e) {
        if (filter(i, e)) {
            index = i;
            return false;
        }
    });
    return index;
}

index = findByFilter(array,function(i,e){ return e.data.title=="Title Two"; });
console.log(index); // prints 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `name` property as index.

Try this code:

```
var indexOfObj = function(array,objName){
    var len = array.length;
    while(--len>=0 && array[len].name!==objName);
    return len;
}
```

This function will return `-1` if the obj wasn't found in the array.